# How To automatically calculate Qtr Revenue given only two dates and Total Revenue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I could use some help writing an excel formula.

Case: Revenue is generated between 2 dates, `Date A` and `Date B`.
These dates could go into the next year and spread across quarters.

How can I split Revenue into `Q1 Revenue`, `Q2 Revenue`, `Q3 Revenue`, `Q4 Revenue` just based on my 2 dates and Total Revenue. 
My thought was first identify which Qtr your dates fall into and then have an if statement that logically figures out the % and multiplies by the revenue.

Currently I'm using this formula to determine Qtr: `=ROUNDUP(MONTH(DateA)/3,0)`.

Similarly for `DateB`.

Then, `=if(DateAQtr=2, ((6/30/2013-DateA)/(DateB-DateA))*Revenue, 0)`
There are clearly problems with this like, what happens if `DateB(end Date)` is in `Q1` of the following year.

Denominator will always be `Date B` - `Date A`, giving you `total days`.
Numerator of `Start Qtr` is `=(LastDayofQtr - Start)`.
Numerator of any quarters in the middle will be the `full qtr length`.
Numerator of `End Qtr` is `=(EndDate - LastDayofPreviousQtr)`.

This is the logic. I'm trying to write into Excel formula to automate the process.

Comment: Are you assuming your revenue is evenly distributed across all days over the period ?

Comment: No. I'm trying to distribute as a % of time.

Comment: Are you ok with using a small table to help you calculate this? If so I have an answer for you.

Comment: I'm interested to see what a solution would look like, because right now I do not have a specific requirement to leave out the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I made some named ranges to help see what is going on.

`A2 = DateA`, `B2 = DateB`, `C2 = Revenue`

`A7 =DATE(YEAR(DateA),1,1)` This is to establish the Q1 date for the DateA entered.

`A8 =EDATE(A7,3)` dragged down to cell A15 as in the picture. This returns the start of the next Quarter.

`B7 =IF(AND(DateA>=A7,DateA<A8),A8-DateA,IF(AND(DateB>=A7,DateB<A8),DateB-A7,IF(AND(A7<DateB,A7>DateA),A8-A7)))` This is checking how the dates compare to the Quarter start dates and returning the number of days our DateA and DateB date range contain for each Quarter.

`C7 ="Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(A7)/3,0)` dragged down to read the Qtr Start Date and return the corresponding Q#.

`D7 =IF(B7=FALSE,"",C7&"-"&YEAR(A7))` returns the Q# and year when the days column is not false.

`E7 =IF(D7="","",(Revenue/(DateB-DateA)*B7/Revenue))` This calculates the percentages of revenue that each quarter contains.

If you change the values of DateA or DateB everything still calculates properly. If you date range is larger than the two years displayed just drag the formulas down to expand the max range.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This worked the way I want it to, now I've just got to figure out how to get it into a sharepoint out of the box solution.